# Where should I call CakeResponse::disableCache() from?

Tags: cakephp

I've been blissfully calling `CakeResponse::disableCache();` from the `beforeFilter()` of `AppController.php` to disable browser caching and it has, as far as I can tell, been working well.

However, since upgrading to PHP5.4, I'm getting the following strict warning:

```
Strict (2048): Non-static method CakeResponse::disableCache() 
should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible 
context [APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 53]
```

The function still seems to be working but the error tells me that I've misunderstood something pretty fundamental and that there's probably a different (and better) way of doing it.

So, if I need browser caching to be disabled on an app-wide basis (ie: `no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate` etc etc) then what's the best way to do this in Cake 2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not accessing the CakeResponse object it how it is intended to be used in an OOP context? as part the controller:

```
$this->response
```

So in your case:

```
$this->response->disableCache();
```

There are also plenty of examples in the docs - like http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#interacting-with-browser-caching

have you read the book prior to asking the question?